# Dynamic generated select; value set as per fetched data in vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have populated form data as follows

```
<div v-for="(daton, key) in server_data">
    <select class="form-select" v-model="form['type_'+key]">
        <option value="none" :selected="daton.type === 'none'?true:false">none</option>
        <option value="link" :selected="daton.type === 'link'?true:false">Link</option>
        <option value="image" :selected="daton.type === 'image'?true:false">image</option>
    </select> 
    <!--there are other inputs here-->
</div>
```

I need to select the data which has the respective value in fetched data.

server data

```
{"1":{"type":"link","link":"link_to_file","hash":"someHash"},"2":{"type":"image","link":"link_to_file","hash":"someHash"}}
```

If type is link then link in select should be selected, and same for image.

Comment: Can you share `server_data`  and `form` object structure

Comment: added server data

Comment: your `v-model` will bind your `select` value on whatever is in the `data()` which in this case is `form[\`type_${key}\`]`, just set the desired value there.